# How to get all commited PBI that are not linked to a PR

Tags: azure-devops

In VSTS, I'm creating a query where I want to fin all the PBI thare are commited, but not linked to a Pull Request.

Here is my query :
[image: Current query]

The problem here is that I get all the commited PBIs, even those that are linked to a PR.

Any idea ?

Many thanks in advance,
Julien

Answer (score 0):

We cannot achieve that with work item query as no pull request related filed can be set in the query.

You can try to write script by calling the REST API with WIQL to get the work item list, then filter the PBIs later.

Please see below articles for details:

- [Wiql - Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=vsts-rest-4.1)
- [Syntax for the Work Item Query Language (WIQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/wiql-syntax?view=vsts)
- [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=vsts-rest-4.1)

Comment: @Julien Ferraro Have you resolved the issue? any update?